# If a Query in A1 = #REF! , clear all cells in range A2:B+lastrow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Query in cell A1 that is grabbing information and displaying it in a different spreadsheet.  When someone types anything into the range that query is displaying in, it gives #REF!  So I thought about making an if criteria that clears all the cells in that range `if('A1' == '#REF!')`  But doesn't seem to be working.  I also set it up so that if A1 != 'Query formula' set it to 'Query formula'

```
  var queryString = '=Query(ImportRange("Spreadsheetid","\'Sheet1\'!A1:Z1000"),"SELECT Col1, Col2 WHERE Col1 != \'\' Order By Col1",1)'
  var lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getLastRow()
  Logger.log(getValue('A1'))///it says it's #REF!
   if('A1' == '#REF!'){
     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('A2:B'+lastRow).clear({contentsOnly: true});
}
if('A1' != queryString){
    setValue('A1',queryString)
}
```

While testing it, it seems like the main issue is the if criteria.  Is it not seeing it as #REF!?  Does it see it as the Query formula even though the logger.log says it equals what it looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to just use 'A1' in your if statement to check the cell. Try defining it separately then doing a check on your variable, for example:

```
function replaceRef() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('SHEET_NAME'); //enter sheet name here

  var value = sh.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var formula =  sh.getRange('A1').getFormula();
  var queryString = '=Query(ImportRange("Spreadsheetid","\'Sheet1\'!A1:Z1000"),"SELECT Col1, Col2 WHERE Col1 != \'\' Order By Col1",1)';
  var lastRow = sh.getLastRow();

  if (value == '#REF!') {
    sh.getRange('A2:B'+lastRow).clear({contentsOnly: true});
  }
  if (formula != queryString) {
    sh.getRange(1, 1).setFormula(queryString); //get cell A1 and set formula
  }
}
```

As you can see, I've made a few changes. The main ones are defining the values you want to check as variables, which I have done in `var value` and `var formula`. You can then use these to compare to the values you're trying in your if statements.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.  I've been testing it for a bit and one thing does pop up now and then is where I put stuff in the way of the Query and it gives the #REF! but then the function doesn't shoot off.  So i delete what's in the way and do it again and again but it's always #REF! until I delete the query and it places itself back and it's acting normal again, it deletes stuff when it equals #REF! but if I do it enough times it starts to just stay #REF! without correcting itself.  Any Reason for this inconsistency?

Comment: @BillKoch I'm not too sure - what triggers have you configured for this script?

Comment: It's ``onChange()``. I have it running a installable trigger.  I have it so that the function to check for the REF! is the first function to run ``onChange()``.  I also tried it where I just put the code directly into onChange().  it might be due to lag. or something.  Where eventually it just breaks and can't be fixed without a reset.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to run the script, I don't see why you need ifs at all.

```
var queryString = 
'=Query(ImportRange("Spreadsheetid","\'Sheet1\'!A1:Z1000"),"SELECT Col1, Col2 WHERE Col1 != \'\' Order By Col1",1)';
             SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('A2:B'+lastRow).clear({contentsOnly: true});
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("a1").setValue(queryString);
```

I'd also consider protecting that range if you are worried about people messing with it.

Comment: Is it possible to protect a range without protecting the whole sheet?

Comment: Thank you for drawing my attention to this.  I had convinced myself that i couldn't do this.